# Swipe buttons/menu with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here are six buttons in the container of 300px width. As you can see the buttons are jumping into new row upon the lack of space which is expected. I'm wondering if there's a way to keep the buttons in one line, but with the possibility of swiping them to the right on mobile device? Box shadow would indicate that there are more buttons to the right.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 8px -5px 20px 0px lightgrey;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <button>Button 3</button>
  <button>Button 4</button>
  <button>Button 5</button>
  <button>Button 6</button>
</div>
```

Comment: for swiping you'll need external libraries

Comment: You can keep them inline by playing with the overflow rule on the div so that the invisible buttons can be rendered outside of the div. And since swiping is a touch event, you can hook a function to that event to move the position of the buttons or the wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is partially going to do what you want, but you need external libraries for swiping on mobile devices ([this one](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js) allows you to detect touch events on touch screen devices).

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 8px -5px 20px 0px lightgrey;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

button {
  margin-right: 4px;
  flex: 1 0 25%;
}

.wrap::-webkit-scrollbar {
    opacity: 0;
}
 
.wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    opacity: 0;
}
 
.wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <button>Button 3</button>
  <button>Button 4</button>
  <button>Button 5</button>
  <button>Button 6</button>
</div>
```

Comment: any library to recommend perhaps?

Comment: @Smithy, I would recommend you to try this library https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js, which allows you to detect touch events, not just on mobile devices but in any touch screen device.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
.wrap { 
     display: flex;
     overflow-x: scroll; 
}
```